# Find if relation exist and map it to boolean in typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Hello guys I would like to know whats the best way to find if a relation exist and map it to a boolean. Or if there is a better way of approaching this I would love to hear it. Im using typeorm and postgresql.

At the moment I have a `User` entity and a `Post` entity which both have a `OneToMany` relation to `LikedPost` entity.

Here is the schema: 
**User:** `id : string`
**Post:** `id : string` | `likedByUser : boolean`
**LikedPost:** `id : string` | `userId : string` | `postId : string`

When I'm querying for posts I would like to check if there is a relation between the user and the posts and then make likedByUser true if the relation exist.

Would love any advice.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly

```
select *, case when u.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as likedByUser 
from posts p
left join user u
  on u.id = p.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous as  "find if a relation exist" can mean:

1. Are the appropriately definitions in place such that a relationship exits?
2. Does the data exist such that satisfies the relationship?"
3. Does the data exist such that satisfies the relationship for a
   particular user, post, or both.

If you mean #1 then you need to query the information_schema. You also need to have the appropriate PKs and FKs defined. If you mean #2, then you still need (or at least should have) the appropriate PKs and FKs defined. Finally #3 is an expansion of #2 for specific values.

```
#1 Relationships properly defines 
with uc(uc_schema, uc_name) as   
     (select rc.unique_constraint_schema,rc.unique_constraint_name
        from information_schema.table_constraints  tc 
        join information_schema.referential_constraints rc 
          on (tc.constraint_schema,tc.constraint_name) =
             (rc.constraint_schema,rc.constraint_name) 
       where (tc.table_schema,tc.table_name,tc.constraint_type) = 
             ('public','likedposts','FOREIGN KEY') 
     )  
select tcCnt = (select count(*) from uc)  
  from ( select distinct count(*)  over() tcCnt  
           from information_schema.table_constraints tc
           join uc 
             on (    tc.constraint_schema = uc_schema
                 and tc.constraint_name   = uc_name
                 and (   (tc.table_schema,tc.table_name) = ('public','posts' )
                      or (tc.table_schema,tc.table_name) = ('public','users' )
                     )
                ) 
        ) sc; 

For #2 and #3 they are all in the format
select exists (select <specific values) ;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6d4f30b43e21934d845f35b695f158e9)

**Model Note**: You should not put the column "likedByUser" on the Post table. The problem being it could easily give a erroneous reading. I.e. a True value when no qualifying entry exists in the likedposts table, or a False value when it does. Just retrieve its value when it is needed.

Comment: His question is about TypeORM, an ORM for Typescript, not raw SQL.